# Order by date expect one that should be last

Tags: mysql, dql

My query:

```
SELECT c FROM MyBundle:Category c ORDER BY c.name = 'Archive', c.createdAt DESC
```

I get

```
Error: Expected end of string, got '='
```

I want all entries to be orded by date except the archive which should be the last. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will sort records in descending order by date, keeping the Archive records at the bottom:

```
SELECT c 
FROM MyBundle:Category c 
ORDER BY case when c.name = 'Archive' then 2 else 1 end, 
    c.createdAt DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d2d0/1)

As an extension to this answer, this is what I had to change to make it work with DQL:

```
SELECT c,
  CASE WHEN c.name = 'Archive' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS HIDDEN sortCondition
  FROM MyBundle:Category c ORDER BY sortCondition, c.createdAt DESC
```

Comment: I get [Syntax Error] line 0, col 75: Error: Expected end of string, got 'WHEN'

Comment: I updated my answer with a working SQL Fiddle example.